# How to use wireshark display filters without network trafic, but with data flow from file

Tags: networking, logging, filtering, wireshark, text-processing

For example, I have text log with sip messages.
I want to filter these messages such as I can to do this in wireshark display filter, for examples with next filter:

```
sip.Method ne REGISTER || sip.CSeq.method ne REGISTER
```

In output I want to make file without messages, that not accepted by filter.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is normally used with `PCAP` files but it can open a plethora of other formats.  [The section 5.2 of the manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOOpenSection.html) has a list of some 30 different formats, notably `ppd logs`, `juniper netscreen` and `apple packet logger`.  Just open the file `File > Open`.

Then you **type your filter** (you can use the keyword `not` in filters) and `Apply` the filter.  Only the packets matched will be displayed.  Now you shall save it with `File > Export Specified Packets`.  In the dialog shown you shall click on `Displayed` and save the file as one of the several format available (although you should really be using the PCAP format for packets, it is widely supported).

---

A lot depends on the format of your log file.  If you have the bytes from the `UDP` messages under `SIP` you likley used some tool to assemble this log.  If the log has no info about the actual raw packets, you might as well use a simple `grep`.

Comment: This good for network traffic, but I have inly text sip messages. Grep is good, but not apply for me such as wireshark filters.

Comment: Wireshark filters are byte offset based (to be accurate, they're actually libpcap filters).  Basically, if you do not have all the bytes of a packet (or at least a format that wireshark can mock most bytes) they will not have a chance to be applied.  If the format is not a known one, dump it here on stack overflow and people can work out a decent `grep`, or maybe `awk`, filter.